# Title to Variable in Email

Tags: php, email

How can i go about adding a title to each variable in the email. I tried:

```
$message .= First Name: $fname;
```

But doesnt work.

```
$message .= $fname;
$message .= $lname;
$message .= $gname;
$message .= $license;
$message .= $myusername;
$message .= $floor;
$message .= $spot;
```

Comment: `$message .= 'First Name:'. $fname;` please read about strings in php: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks!, can i choose this as the answer or you have to post as the answer?

Comment: This question shows a complete lack of effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to concatenate the strings like so

```
$message .= 'First Name: '. $fname;
```

you should read the section in the manual on [strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)